# Account Lockout not showing up in Event Viewer

Tags: windows-server-2008, user-accounts, eventviewer

I wrote a powershell script to send me an email for Account Lockout events when I noticed there were almost none in the Event Viewer. I used a test user and attempted five bad logins, and got the message that Testo was locked out. Then I checked my Event Viewer in both DCs. Nothing! I found this [Account lockouts not in Event Viewer](https://serverfault.com/questions/659291/account-lockouts-not-in-event-viewer), but that did not work when I locked Testo afterward. What am I missing?

Some more details:
Filtering Event Viewer on 4740
Testo is AD user that previous to test logged in successfully
GPO: Audit Account Lockout set to Audit Success and Failure events
The DC servers are 2016 and 2008
The workstation is Win 7

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the script to send an alert when an specific event (4740) occurred on your Domain controllers. In my case, I created a Task (Task Scheduled) to do this. Remember, You need to enable the Security audit policies on your domain controllers in order to log these kind of events.

Also, make sure to point your screen to the correct log and source:

Log Name: Security

Source: Microsoft-Windows-Security-Auditing

Event ID: 4740

Check this link for more details (Is related to 2008 but is the same on 2016): http://techgenix.com/Event-IDs-Windows-Server-2008-Vista-Revealed/